# minimalist PyOpenGL example in PyQt5 application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyopengl

I am learning `PyOpenGL` and use it in `PyQt5` application. I am trying to convert some of my old simple examples from `C++`/`Qt` to `Python`. The following example should draw white triangle on black background. At least it does in the corresponding `C++`/`Qt` code. But it does nothing, just a black window. Any ideas what I am missing? Note that I need the 'modern' approach using shaders (however according to my knowledge - I may be wrong - the following code should just use a default trivial shader, i.e white color in 2D) instead of all that oldish `glBegin()`, `glEnd()`.

```
import numpy as np
from OpenGL import GL
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget, QApplication


class OpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def initializeGL(self):
        vertices = np.array([0.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0], dtype=np.float32)

        bufferId = GL.glGenBuffers(1)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId)
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size, vertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 0, 0)

    def paintGL(self):
        GL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)


app = QApplication([])
widget = OpenGLWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, finally, I found my errors:

```
GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)  # nbytes instead of size
```

and

```
GL.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 0, None)  # i.e. None instead of 0
```

The complete minimalistic example is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from OpenGL import GL
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget, QApplication


class OpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def initializeGL(self):
        vertices = np.array([0.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0], dtype=np.float32)

        bufferId = GL.glGenBuffers(1)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId)
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 0, None)

    def paintGL(self):
        GL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)


app = QApplication([])
widget = OpenGLWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note that this however does not follow the 'best practice' - you should be using shaders and VAO! This code is really just the shortest possible...

Answer (score 0):

If you use PySide2 (it is an official binding for Qt) you need to write this line of code

```
QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)
```

main.py

```
import numpy as np
from OpenGL import GL
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget, QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt


class OpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def initializeGL(self):
        vertices = np.array([0.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0], dtype=np.float32)

        bufferId = GL.glGenBuffers(1)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId)
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 0, None)

    def paintGL(self):
        GL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)


QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)
app = QApplication([])
widget = OpenGLWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```